# Are data in memory without variable names still objects in R?

Tags: r, oop, object, data-structures

I'm trying to conceptualize what exactly the difference is between data in R before and after we assign them a variable name. For example, is there any difference between the output of `read.csv(file = 'inflammation.csv'` and `df <- read.csv(file = 'inflammation.csv')` other than that the latter allows us to access the object because it exists in a namespace?

For the first case, `read.csv`, the documentation for [read.csv](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) states that the function reads a file in table format and creates a data frame from it. I'm interpreting this as it creates an object of class, 'data.frame', but it just doesn't have a variable assignment yet. In other words, you can still have an object in R without variable assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct. read.csv without an assignment will create a data frame, but there is no way for you to access it. Assignment to a variable creates a reference to the object, which allows you to manipulate it. An explanation of object behavior and tools to investigate object are found at https://www.brodieg.com/2019/02/18/an-unofficial-reference-for-internal-inspect/.